# Potential energy and bounded motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, atoms, molecules

In the chapter of energy of the Kleppner's book, Introduction to Mechanics, he explain diagrams of energy and the concept of bounded motion. There is an example which explains that if a motion is bounded or not can depend on the total mechanical energy, that is the case of the motion of an atom which experiment the repulsive/attractive force due the presence another atom. Also in the chapter explains that the value of the total energy is arbitrary, so my question is: how such physical phenomena can depend of the arbitrary election of the value of the total energy?

Comment: Bounded motion **means** that the total energy in the system is negative.

Comment: @Sam The total E of a particle in a $1D$ box with infinite boundary potential isn't negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy in question is the total energy of the system. In one dimensional case we can write:
$$E = \frac{mv^2}{2} + V(x),$$
where $\frac{mv^2}{2}$ is the kinetic energy and $V(x)$ is the potential energy. The particle velocity is then given by
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\left[E-V(x)\right]}$$
Let us take, e.g., parabolic potential: $V(x) = kx^2/2$. As the particle moves in the direction where the potential grows it experiences a force that slows its motion, reducing its velocity and its kinetic energy, till it stops at the point $x_0$ determined by $E= kx_0^2/2$. The particle thus moves between the stopping points $x_0 = \pm\sqrt{2E/k}$, its motion is bounded. For a harmonic oscillator the motion is always bounded, the energy determines only the amplitude of the oscillations, i.e. how far the particle climbs onto the potential.
If, however, the potential energy has a peak, and the energy of the particle is higher than the peak, the particle wouldn't stop unbounded (unless there is another potential barrier to stop it).

The close analogy to the case of an electron and an atom is the movement of satellites in the gravity field of the Earth. E.g., the motion of the Moon is bounded, just like the motion of any artificial satellite orbiting the Earth. In order to send a satellite to Mars, it needs to have velocity higher than the *escape velocity*, i.e. it needs to have energy above the gravitational potential barrier of the Earth. Then it leaves and does not come back - its motion is unbounded.

Comment: I agree whit all your examples and concepts, but the potential energy function to describe the interaction between two atoms is a special one; the equation is: $U(x) = \epsilon [(r_{0}/r)^2-2(r_{0}/r)^6]$. If the total energy is positive, then is a unbounded motion; if the total energy is negative then is a bounded motion.

Comment: It works in exactly the same way: the potential goes to zero at $r\rightarrow +\infty$, so, if an incident atom comes with positive energy, it will be scattered and leave to infinity. What might be confusing is that the peak of the potential has energy above zero, which means that for energy below the peak height but greater than zero one has in fact two possibilities: bounded and unbounded motion, depending on the initial conditions. Note that in quantum chase the bound state is unstable. Another example, frequently used to study diffusion escape or tunneling: U(x) = $x^3-bx^2$